How can I fix wrong number of k-points error in Qantum ESPRESSO while running pw2wannier90.x?
when I run pw2wannier90.x < pw2wan.in > pw2wan.out
I get this message:
Spin CASE ( default = unpolarized )

  Wannier mode is: standalone     

  -----------------
  *** Reading nnkp 
  -----------------

  Checking info from wannier.nnkp file

  - Real lattice is ok
  - Reciprocal lattice is ok
  Something wrong! 
  numk=          64  iknum=         128

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine pw2wannier90 (64):
     Wrong number of k-points
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     stopping ...

here is my scf file,
*&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  etot_conv_thr =   4.0000000000d-04
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'aiida'
  pseudo_dir = './pseudo/'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
/
&SYSTEM
  degauss =   2.2049585400d-02
  ecutrho =   4.0000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   5.0000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 40
  nosym = .false.
  nspin = 2
  ntyp = 4
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'cold'
  starting_magnetization(1) =   3.5714285714d-01
  starting_magnetization(2) =   1.0000000000d-01
  starting_magnetization(3) =   1.0000000000d-01
  starting_magnetization(4) =   4.5454545455d-01
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   8.0000000000d-09
  electron_maxstep = 80
  mixing_beta =   4.0000000000d-01
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Mo     95.96 Mo_ONCV_PBEsol-1.0.upf
O      15.9994 O.pbesol-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF
Pb     207.2 Pb.pbesol-dn-kjpaw_psl.0.2.2.UPF
Sc     44.955912 Sc_ONCV_PBEsol-1.0.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Pb           0.2500000000       0.2500000000       0.2500000000 
Pb           0.2500000000       0.7500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.7500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.2500000000       0.2500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.2500000000       0.7500000000       0.2500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.2500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.7500000000       0.2500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.2500000000       0.2500000000 
Sc           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
Sc           0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Sc           0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
Sc           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
Mo           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Mo           0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
Mo           0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
Mo           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.2556000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.7444000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.7444000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.2556000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.7444000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.2556000000 
O            0.2556000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.7556000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.7556000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.7444000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.2444000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.2444000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.2444000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.7444000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.2444000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.7556000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.2556000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.7556000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.2444000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.2444000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.7444000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.7556000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.7556000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.2556000000 
K_POINTS automatic
4 4 4 0 0 0
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      8.1343000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       8.1343000000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       0.0000000000       8.1343000000*

my nscf file :
*&CONTROL
  calculation = 'nscf'
  etot_conv_thr =   4.0000000000d-04
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'aiida'
  pseudo_dir = './pseudo/'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
/
&SYSTEM
  degauss =   2.2049585400d-02
  ecutrho =   4.0000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   5.0000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 40
  nosym = .false.
  nspin = 2
  ntyp = 4
  occupations = 'fixed'
  smearing = 'cold'
  starting_magnetization(1) =   3.5714285714d-01
  starting_magnetization(2) =   1.0000000000d-01
  starting_magnetization(3) =   1.0000000000d-01
  starting_magnetization(4) =   4.5454545455d-01
  nbnd = 40
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   8.0000000000d-09
  electron_maxstep = 80
  mixing_beta =   4.0000000000d-01
  diago_full_acc = .true.
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Mo     95.96 Mo_ONCV_PBEsol-1.0.upf
O      15.9994 O.pbesol-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF
Pb     207.2 Pb.pbesol-dn-kjpaw_psl.0.2.2.UPF
Sc     44.955912 Sc_ONCV_PBEsol-1.0.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Pb           0.2500000000       0.2500000000       0.2500000000 
Pb           0.2500000000       0.7500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.7500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.2500000000       0.2500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.2500000000       0.7500000000       0.2500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.2500000000       0.7500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.7500000000       0.2500000000 
Pb           0.7500000000       0.2500000000       0.2500000000 
Sc           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
Sc           0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Sc           0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
Sc           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
Mo           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Mo           0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
Mo           0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
Mo           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.2556000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.7444000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.7444000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.2556000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.7444000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.2556000000 
O            0.2556000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.7556000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.7556000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.7444000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.2444000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.2444000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.2444000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.7444000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.2444000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.7556000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.2556000000       0.5000000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.7556000000       0.0000000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.2444000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.2444000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.7444000000 
O            0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.7556000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.7556000000 
O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.2556000000 
K_POINTS crystal
64
  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.25000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.25000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.25000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.25000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.50000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.50000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.50000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.50000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.75000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.75000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.75000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.00000000  0.75000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.00000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.00000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.00000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.25000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.25000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.25000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.25000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.50000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.50000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.50000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.50000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.75000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.75000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.75000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.25000000  0.75000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.00000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.00000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.25000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.25000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.25000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.25000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.50000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.50000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.50000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.50000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.75000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.75000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.75000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.50000000  0.75000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.00000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.00000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.00000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.25000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.25000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.25000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.25000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.50000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.50000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.50000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.50000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.75000000  0.00000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.75000000  0.25000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.75000000  0.50000000  1.562500e-02
  0.75000000  0.75000000  0.75000000  1.562500e-02

CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      8.1343000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       8.1343000000       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       0.0000000000       8.1343000000*

If anyone can help me, I will be thankful.

+1 but please proofread before posting.

Have you tried sticking closely to one of the example cases closely? I don't think you should be making your own list of k points like that. The wannier90 user manual definitely covered the k points bits quite extensively, and you should just follow the instructions.

I have also noticed that you have magnetism turned on, nspins=2, whereas wannier90 you have it as spinless. This might be where the problem lies.

Did you try setting nosym = .true. in nscf input? See here: https://www.mail-archive.com/wannier@lists.quantum-espresso.org/msg00227.html

Please, first check the output of your nscf run. There, you should found the 64 kpoints, if there are more kpoints, probably the output explain why it happens.

The problem is in either your seedname.win or your pw2wan.in file, actually. The hint is in the error message: pw2wannier90 expected 64 k-points, but it found 128 (twice as many).
The way Quantum ESPRESSO handles (collinear) spin polarization (nspin = 2) is by doubling the number of k-points: in your case, it stores the 64 spin-up k-points, then follows them with 64 more spin-down k-points. So there are 128 in total.
You have to warn wannier90 about this by specifying spin = 'up' or spin = 'down' in wan.win, and you have to warn pw2wannier90 by writing spin_component = 'up' (or 'down'). Wannier90 might be able to do the calculation anyway (probably it only looks at the spin-up k-points, which are stored first), but pw2wannier90 will fail because spin_component defaults to none.
